# Backspace not working in command prompt ssh (openssh) on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, command-line, ssh, openssh

recently upgraded to windows 10 and the ssh command in command prompt was no longer recognized. I installed openssh (7.4P1.1) and am able to ssh into a server. Everything seems to work except backspace. When I press backspace I get an extra character instead which looks like a weird rectangular thing.

Windows 10 Pro

Answer (score 1):

Apparently when I use `stty sane` after I login it works.

Comment: Thanks for closing the loop on your question.  Is there any insight you can add to help others with a similar problem?